# How do I properly call setters on a return constant referenced class member

Tags: c++, class, getter-setter, mutable

My problem is that I am trying to access none constant setter of a constant reference of a class member resulting in the error(C2662). If I make the values being set mutable, and the setter constant, then I am okay, but I have read that you should avoid doing this, but can't find another way to do it.

Definition of vector2D:

```
class vector2D {
    int _x;
    int _y;
public:
    vector2D() :
    _x(0),
    _y(0) {};

    // Getters
    int xGet() { return _x;};
    int yGet() { return _y;};

    // Setters
    void xSet(int x) {
        if (x > 100) {
            _x = 100;
            return;

        } else if (x < 0) {
            _x = 0;
            return;

        } else {
            _x = x;
            return;
        }
    };

    void ySet(int y) {
        if (y > 100) {
            _y = 100;
            return;

        } else if (y < 0) {
            _y = 0;
            return;

        } else {
            _y = y;
            return;
        }
    };
};
```

Definition of npc :

```
class npc {
    vector2D _position;
public:
    npc () {};
    const vector2D& positionGet() const{
        return _position;
    };
};
```

main.cpp :

```
main () { 
    vector2D myPos;
    myPos.xSet(2);    //Okay

    npc myGuy;
    myGuy.positionGet().xSet(2);    //C2662

    return 0;
}
```

What I have tried :

I tried to make xSet/ySet constant functions, but that then gives me an error(expresion must be a modifiable lvalue), which makes sense. I have been reading articles about this, but the correct way has never really been clear.

I tried making x/y mutable, and then that would let me make the setter functions constant, which does get rid of the error, but then I read that a lot of people say not to use mutable, which what other way should this be done?

I also tried to make the returned value of '_position' none constant, but isn't that not safe to do???

Note : I am also trying hard to make my questions better, and so please message/leave comment on how I could have asked this better :D

---

### EDIT: What I have found out

So what a lot of people suggest is just to return a none constant reference of '_position', but the problem I have found with this is that you can directly assign values to the returned reference.

```
vector2D newPos;
myGuy.positionGet() = newPos;
```

Which is bad because the returned value is a private member, so therefore shouldn't be able to be directly assigned.
 It is also bad because if the npc is passed to a function by reference, and then the above is done it calls the destructor on the vector2D once it goes out of scope.

```
void functTest (npc & ch1) {
    vector2D c1;
    ch1.positionGet() = c1;

    return;
}
```

which for some reason also destroys ch1._position ???

Comment: "I also tried to make the returned value of '_position' none constant, but isn't that not safe to do???" absolutely okay to return non const ref, it all depends what you or users are going to do with it afterwards

Comment: @OlegBogdanov thanks! I was wondering does the private scope still protect it from lets say myGuy.positionGet() = somePosition; I also ran into a problem if my program trying to destruct the referenced object(I will try to give a better example of this, might have been because I was returning a pointer to the object on accident XD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your getter to return a mutable reference, then *do that*.

You want to call `positionGet()` and get an object that you can modify.

So don't make it `const`!

```
vector2D& positionGet() {
    return _position;
};
```

Simple as.

Comment: Is this safe? I mean you are returning the reference(memory adress) of the private member '_position'

Comment: Does the private still protect it from lets say. myGuy.position.Get() = somePosition; ?

Comment: @XanNava: No. You are making a function to allow the world to access this variable and change it. Therefore, the world can access this variable and change it. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Well doesn't making some variables mutable, and others not, only make the mutable parts changeable, where returning a none constant reference make those other parts vulnerable? Honestly I am a noob, but I love to do everything as right as I can, so thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @XanNava: After a full bottle of prosecco, I only have a very limited understanding of what you're saying, but my initial answer is: yes, that's true, but you should make things `mutable` when they need to be mutable in a `const` context (e.g. mutexes), not because you haven't designed your interface properly. If your getter should return a mutable reference to some property of your class, don't make it `const`. Making it `const` would be lying.

Comment: LOL I will be drink soon to, but to clarify. what I was saying is that if you don't return a constant reference you can do myGuy.position.Get() = somePosition; which is directly modifying a private class member. If you do however return a constant reference of 'vector2D' then you can't change the returned value, but you still can make method calls, which doesn't destroy the data abstraction.

Comment: myGuy.positionGet() = somePosition; *

Comment: @XanNava: Well, yeah, sure. But if those constant method accesses were sufficient, you wouldn't be asking this question, right?

Comment: True... I posted the problems I found in my main post in higher detail. I just hope there is a better way then either. A side note do you know if mutable is still bad for multi-threading? All the info I can find about mutable is outdated.

Comment: @XanNava: `mutable` has absolutely nothing to do with multi-threading, and never has done

Answer (score 0):

You could provide both mutable and constant interface for the position:

```
class npc {
    vector2D _position;
public:
    npc () {};
    const vector2D& position() const { return _position; };
    vector2D& mutable_position() { return _position; };
};
```

Yes, when you call mutable_position() a reference to the private member will be returned, but if that is the intention of the programmer (as indicated by the explicit use of "mutable_" in the call), then it should be okay.